# Is there a way to execute a function AFTER all shortcodes has been executed? (or later)

Tags: php, wordpress

I put these in a post

```
[fcolors url="sdfsd"]
[fcolors url="sdfsd2"]
```

There could X number of shortcodes (not always 2)

After both above shortcodes has been executed I want to remove a file.

I was thinking of something like

```
class fcolors {

public function __destruct() {
    unlink 'c:\test.txt';
}

}

$x = new fcolors();
unset ($x);
```

but obviously `__destruct` does not work because PHP handles cleaning up very quickly and the `__destruct()` won't execute (in extreme cases I guess it would).

I can not do like this:

```
$x = new fcolors();
unlink 'c:\test.txt';
```

because then the `c:\test.txt` would/could be deleted before shortcodes are finished generating the code I want.

Comment: And what about create a method like your destruct and put in it first unlink and second unset?

Comment: @hokusai - dont understand? What do you mean?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld if you're willing to import 3rd-party libraries, my Shortcode library can parse and return found shortcodes, you can count them and use that information for any purpose: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk - thanks for that! I don't want to use third-party if I don't really really need it. Your code seems excellent, but the reason why I don't want to use it is because I prefer to have as litte depencies as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of how many times your shortcode is called. For example inside your shortcode function you can write to a text file every time the shortcode is called. If the value in the file is 2 you can remove the required file

Comment: I've tried that, but that requires that you know how many shortcodes there are on the page. It could be 2, but it could also be 5.